# How to remove extra space around accented characters in math mode and \mathit?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, accents

I wasn't able to find a solution for my case so far.

I need to write pseudocode and we (a group of professors) choose to use the Cormen et. al style, as available in package `clrscode3e`. To typeset variables, there is the command `\id`, which uses `\mathit`.

The problem is that we need to use accented characters as variable names (in Portuguese), and `\mathit` adds extra spacing around it.

The following MWE shows the spacing I want (the expected behaviour), my workaround, the default inline math mode and an ugly solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% My attempt
\newcommand{\newtilde}[1]{\hspace{-0.1em}\tilde{#1}\hspace{-0.1em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
    Spacing I want & $ \mathit{ffaaa} $ \\
    My solution & $ \mathit{ffa\newtilde{a}a} $ \\
    Standard solution & $ \mathit{ffa\tilde{a}a} $ \\
    In math mode & $ ffa\tilde{a}a $ \\
    Ugly solution & $ ffa\!\tilde{a}\!a $ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

For reference, this is the relevant code extracted from `clrscode3e.sty` (comment added by me):

```
\newcommand{\text@hyphens}{\mathcode`\-=`\-\relax} % hyphens instead of minus sign
\newcommand{\id}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{\text@hyphens#1}}}
```

Using `\mathord` has no effect and anythink like `\DeclareMathSymbol` is far beyond my knowledge in TeX.

Is there a better solution than using my `\newtilde`?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: `\textit` can be used in math mode (although it really isn't advertised), so `$ \textit{ffa\~aa} $` should work perfectly well.

Comment: Your solution doesn't create enough space in `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`. @barbarabeeton's solution works in all cases.

Comment: I guess this workaround is clean enough to solve my problem. I'll make some more tests, as variables can include subscripts and greek letters. Thanks to @barbarabeeton. Also thanks to SandyG, as I wasn't thinking about changing the font size (yet).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `\mathit` if you plan to add accents to your variable names.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\id}[1]{\textnormal{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\id{ffaãa-bb}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a solution, but I forgot to say in the original post that variable names could include greek letters and subscripts. The original `\id` is supposed to be in math mode also. Anyway, this can be a cleaner workaround. Thanks.